# Accessing a Key in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I transfer a HashMap from Java side to Javascript side and both I can debug my map on java side and I can see on browser console

If I write: `console.log(responseFromServer[0].userAttributes);`

```
Object
  cn: Array[1]
  sn: Array[1]
  uid: Array[1]
```

But when I try to write

```
console.log(responseFromServer[0].userAttributes['uid']);
```

or

```
console.log(responseFromServer[0].userAttributes.uid);
```

I see `null`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe the array stored in `userAttributes.uid` contains the string or value `null`? Since we don't know the data, there is not much we can do. This is has nothing to do with JSON btw, you have a normal JavaScript object.

Comment: Post here an example of `responseFromServer`.

Comment: Also include how you're requesting the data in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am using DWR and i missed the errors on Java console about missing converter.

I added my bean to dwr.xml:

```
<dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.entity.OrganizationAttributeValue"/>
```